# How to handle browser back button event in a particular controller?

Tags: angularjs

i want to handle the browser back button event on particular controller(not every route change , only for a particular controller), the back should not change the route as it is for an ng-include change

Comment: @Niyaz- can you add your code.

Answer (score 3):

In the `$scope` of the controller listen for the `$locationChangeStart` event. In the event handler determine if the change is allowed and if not cancel the location change by calling `preventDefault`.

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl) {

  if(!allowed /* inject your logic here */) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

});
```