# Handle browser back button with angular in controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, routes, back-button

I want to handle browser back button with angular, i have tried many solution but i cant find one which is fulfill my requirement, 
here is my tried `code`.

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
   if(!allowed /* inject your logic here */) {
       event.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

it is working fine when i go to particular page from my app, but if go from e.g www.google.com direct to that particular page by pasting link then it just get back to Google. 
what is actually i want handle both scenario of back button.
 
is it possible?
I will really appreciate your response, 

these are the links I have tried but problem remain same.
[How to detect browser back button click event using angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813850/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-click-event-using-angular)
[How to handle browser back button event in a particular controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34127265/how-to-handle-browser-back-button-event-in-a-particular-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using 'window.onbeforeunload'?

For example:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() 
{ 
   //Do whatever here for example prompt user 
   return "Are you sure you want to go back?"; 
};
```